# selenium driver value returning as NULL for website

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi Below are the code,

Issue:
driver value under Acti_01Login page is retunring driver value as NULL, hence it is thorwing exception. How to handle and make sure its not returning the NULL value.

```
////////////////////////////Page Object Model:
public class Acti_01LoginPage
{
    private static WebElement element = null;
    static WebDriverWait wait;


    //Username TextBox
    public static WebElement input_TxtUsername(WebDriver driver)
     {
    System.out.println("Driver in Action login page "+ driver);  
    try
    {
        element =driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        Log.info("Username textbox element is found");
        //System.out.println(element);

    }
    catch (WebDriverException e)
    {
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            Log.info("Username textbox element is not found due to "+e.getMessage());
    }
     return element;
 }

//ActionOpenBrowser
package funcModule;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import utility.Constant;

public class Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser 
{

    WebDriver driver=null;

        public  WebDriver openBrowser(String sBrowserName) throws Exception
        {


            if(sBrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mozilla"))
            {

                driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                driver.get(Constant.URL);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                }
            else if(sBrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
            {

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get(Constant.URL);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            }

            return driver;
        }

}

Callin in Main function:
public class POMtest1 {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.setup();

        Acti_01LoginPage.input_TxtUsername(driver).sendKeys("vjha9009");

        Acti_01LoginPage.input_TxtPassword(driver).sendKeys("Password123");
        Acti_01LoginPage.click_BtnLogin(driver).click();


    }

}
```

Request you to help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not able to see code for setup method but calling

```
  Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.setup();
```

I hope you need to use below one in POMtest1 instead of above one

```
  driver=Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.openBrowser("Mozilla");
```

good to use public static WebDriver driver.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: My mistake:
Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.setup(); is wrong I have used

Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.openBrowser("Mozilla");

and same I am calling from
public class Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser 
public static  WebDriver openBrowser(String sBrowserName) throws Exception
     {
  
           
         if(sBrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mozilla"))
         {
  
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          
          driver.get(Constant.URL);
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           
             }
  }

Comment: use this driver=Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.openBrowser("Mozilla"); and pass this driver to all below methods, you dont get null point exception

Comment: thanks it is working, please let me know what is the reason behind the same.
It would be nice if you can provide me the link for the ame.

Comment: method Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.openBrowser("Mozilla"); will starting the webdriver may firefoxdriver here and returning the driver instance. we need to collect same driver and to use it another methods. if not it will throw null exception as there is no driver. so use  driver=Acti_03ActionOpenBrowser.openBrowser("Mozilla");  got it

Comment: this answer helps user to solve his issue.  why it is down voted? not sure why people criticize with down vote without explaining the what is wrong